# ¿Cómo asignar un valor a un elemento de un array llamantolo desde una variable que contiene su nombre en Kotlin?

Tags: array, kotlin, variables

Tengo un *array* de la siguiente manera:

```kotlin
lista = arrayOf(1,2,3,4)
```

Y una variable:

```
nombreArray = "lista"
```

Y deseo asignar un valor al *array* a partir del contenido de la variable así:

```kotlin
nombreArray[0] = 7
```

Para que el *array* quede así:

```kotlin
lista = (7,2,3,4)
```

**¿Qué método debo utilizar?**

Answer (score 0):

**El tipo dinámico no se admite en el código destinado a la JVM.**

Al ser un lenguaje de tipado estático, Kotlin todavía tiene que interoperar con entornos sin tipado o con tipado suelto, como el ecosistema de JavaScript. Para facilitar estos casos de uso, el dynamictipo está disponible en el idioma:

val dyn: dynamic = ...

El tipo dinamico básicamente desactiva el verificador de tipos de Kotlin:

Se dynamicpuede asignar un valor del tipo a cualquier variable o pasar a cualquier lugar como parámetro.

Cualquier valor puede asignarse a una variable del dynamictipo o pasarse a una función que lo tome dynamiccomo parámetro.

arroja este error

Unsupported [Dynamic types are not supported in this context]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar tus arrays en un `Map` y asignarle una key de tipo String a cada uno.

```
val arrays = mapOf(
    "lista" to arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4),
    "lista2" to arrayOf(2, 2, 2)
)
```

Luego lo usas así

```
val nombreArray = "lista"
arrays[nombreArray]!![0] = 7
```

El `!!` es necesario porque `arrays[nombreArray]` retornará `null` si no existe ningún array con ese nombre. Si quieres que sea null-safe debes hacerlo así

```
arrays[nombreArray]?.set(0, 7)
```